# Use parent site's header for Wordpress blog

Tags: php, database, wordpress, header, footer

I've just finished a client's site: http://wallstreetprep.com

The site uses three separate databases -- one for the main site, and one each for two separate Wordpress installations. Using the site's main nav to map things out: "IB Industry Overview, IB Industry Resources and IB Salary Overview" all use one Wordpress installation. "Visit the WSP Blog" uses another Wordpress installation. The rest of the site is a non-Wordpress database — let's call this the "parent site."

My question: Is it possible (simple?) to use the parent site's header and footer php files for the Wordpress installations. By this, I mean using the same php files rather than duplicates. In the current site, I had to duplicate the parent site's header and footer on the other two databases so the nav appears to be global to the user. This is obviously very inefficient since if I have to change something in the header or footer, I have to do it in 3 different places. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The parent's header is  static? It has no dependencies, for example PHP code that uses functions only available on the parent site?

Comment: why not use a normal php include, in your wp theme header file? delete everything (if you dont rely on any get_header info) then just inlcude('parentsite/theme/header.php')? or if it really comes to it, just paste in, what get_header USED to output! into your parent theme header file, then dito for footer?

Comment: @calle: The header only contains links to php pages on the parent site and a few links to pages on the different Wordpress blogs. So I suppose that means no dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with simple php includes.  Something like this:

```
<?php include '/path/to/header.php'; ?>
```

and then the same thing for the footer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Chris. I can't seem to get this working. Here's what I did. The html for the site navigation was formerly written into the parent site's header.php file. (The parent site is not Worpress, but houses 2 Wordpress blogs.) I took that html out and put it into it's own file called "sitenav.php." I included that in the parent site's header.php file by inserting: <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/sitenav.php";?>

This worked fine here. However, that php include does not work when placed in the Wordpress header.php file (or any of my wordpress files). Ideas?

Comment: As a test, try <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/sitenav.php";?> and see what you get.  Make sure the path is correct.

Comment: hmm - this makes the browser generate text that shows the path to the file: /var/www/vhosts/wallstreetprep.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs/includes/sitenav.php

Comment: Is that where sitenav.php is?  Remember that with includes you use the complete local path on the machine, not the path from web root.

Comment: yes, the path that the browser is showing is where sitenav.php is. So, using <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/sitenav.php";?> is generating the correct path to the correct file. But why is the browser showing the path and not rendering the html of sitenav.php?

Comment: That's what echo is supposed to do, I just suggested it for testing.  You might try <?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/sitenav.php"); ?>

Comment: ah ok. require not working either. will do some further digging.